# Rails error with asset pipeline "Asset filtered out and will not be served"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am constantly getting this error

```
Asset filtered out and will not be served: 'Rails.application.config.assets.precompile..."
```

and so on for both

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "login" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "login" %>
```

I've searched on stackoverflow and read things to find out that I can simply just add the files into the precompiled list as the error says, but I don't know why I have to add this is when I **already have the manifest file with**

```
//= require_tree .
```

I've seen ruby applications where manifest files take care of the job. What's happening?

Comment: Do you have the main `javascripts/login.js` and `stylesheets/login.scss` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused about what the manifest does.

`//= require_tree .` only merges those files into a single large file, whatever file the manifest is in. (Presumably `application.js`; the whole point being that Sprockets generates a single file that users can cache, instead of needing to load multiple.) It doesn't keep them around as separate files--for that you need to insert them in your `assets.rb`, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

add `login.css` and `login.js` into your `config/initializers/assets.rb`

more information is described under [Precompiling Assets Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)